# 3D cube transition in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a screen (or part of the screen) switch to another part in a 3D cube-like transition.
I'm talking about 2 normal Android UI parts, not raw graphics rendered on a canvas.

How would you approach this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The project was cancelled a long time ago so I didn't get to implement this. If the answer below works, please comment so on the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Did you ever get this implemented? I am looking for the same answer.

Comment: Since you cannot compose a Cube-like animation with the crappy standard Animation subclasses - and you cannot specify custom Animation implementations in XML this should be pretty "unfixable", refer to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7824) which has received no love from Google.

Comment: have u got any solution?

Comment: The project was cancelled a long time ago so I didn't get to implement this. If the answer below works, please comment so on the answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: To the guy who closed the question - what is not clear here? 3D cube-like transition seems like a very precise description. The question was upvoted 13 times so I guess most readers understand it. Looking at the tags in your profile, I don't even see 'Android' there - why mess around with questions in knowledge areas you don't understand?

Comment: Some people in stack overflow really embarrass the entire moderator group, this guy who closed is a .NET developer. I really doubt how much he understands about android

Answer (score 21):

I suppose you want a transaction like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBueHhBwujE)

Ok let's say you have a viewswitcher with 2 children.
You need to access each child separately when they draw. You can do that by extending the ViewSwicher class to your own MyViewSwitcher and enable static transformations

```
public class MyViewSwitcher extends ViewSwitcher {


//DO THAT FOR ALL CONSTRUCTORS
    public PViewSwitcher(Context context) {
        super(context);
               setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true); 
               ....
    }



        //Now you have to override getChildStaticTransformation
            @Override
            protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {

   //enable drawing cache to each child to get  smoother transactions
  child.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        //To identify if the child is the first or the second of the viewSwitcher do that
       if (child == getChildAt(0)) {
                //Here i will transform the first child


             }
       if (child == getChildAt(1)) {
                //Here i will transform the second child

             }   


    return true;
        }
```

**

> Now the position part.

**
What you need to know is the position of each child. You can do that by getting the 
position of each child relative to its parent. `child.getLeft()` does that for you.
and `float centerChild = child.getLeft()+(child.getWidth()/2f)` . Whatever animation you do 
has to have centerChild  as a reference.

So you can tell rotate the child to the x axis based on the distance it's center ( `centerChild`) has from the parents distance (`getWidth()/2f`) .

So

> float distanceFromCenter = getWidth() -centerChild;

Now you have your reference points.

**

> Now to the transformations part.

**

You have to alter the transformation. To do that you have to access it's matrix.

```
//Setup the matrix and alter it
 Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
 t.clear();
 t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
```

//Here you can play with the matrix..
so by doing

```
matrix.postTranslate(-distance, 0);
```

you already get a funny looking animation.

Then let's rotate the image based on it's position.

```
matrix.postRotate(distance /40f);
matrix.preTranslate(-child.getWidth()/2f , -child.getHeight()/2f);
matrix.postTranslate(child.getWidth()/2f , child.getHeight()/2f);
```

You get a funny looking rotation when the viewswitcher animates.

**

> Now to the 3D Part!

**

Android gives access to the camera class`. android.graphics.Camera`

What camera class does is it modifies the 3x3 matrix and provides 3D transformations.

Inside getChildStaticTransformation()...

```
    Camera mCamera;
    mCamera.save();
    mCamera.rotateY(distance/40f); //you should divide by the parent's width so your       rotation values are 0>=rotation >= MAX_ROTATION
    mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
   mCamera.restore();
```

So now to get your 3D cude animation just figure the rotation values based on the parent distance and apply it to each child with

> mCamera.rotateX(deg).

Comment: pls share more info how to implement ?

Comment: @weakwire share any info how to implement

Comment: Can i get any sample Regarding this, i am implementing in my project

Comment: Since this answer got upvoted but no one reported that it actually works (and my project was cancelled a long time ago), please comment if the answer works. If it does, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Check out here for demo `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245031/how-to-implement-cube-transition-effect-animation-on-viewpager-in-android/27774196#27774196`

Answer (score 1):

Animations between Inter-activity transitions can be done by using [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29).

Here is a pretty good [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=32766) to start.

---

Jelly beans has support for `LayoutTransistion` and [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) but I don't think even armed with this, you'll be able to pull off 3D cube transistions.

Comment: the tutorial itself has nothing to do with the 3d cube like animation. +1 anyway :)

Comment: Yeah I know thanks :) I'm hoping OP will have to animate that himself. If I do find a way (without using the usual graphics on canvas method) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Reno how to solve this issue?