# How to set 3d flip animation for child of gridview

Tags: android

i am working on animation, i want to give animation to the child view of costume grid view. and that animation like 3d Transition for chile(image view) of android.

I am using the concept is as per http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html.

But i can not able to animate the imageview of gridview.

Please help me.

Comment: By right if you apply an animation on the parent grid view it will apply to all child views.. thus it should work.. did u start the animation?

Comment: I have try it but not working. as per api demo of android i can able to rotate whole grid view  but not able to rotate only one image of grid view at a time.

Comment: Hi rejinderi have you ever try this type of animation? if yes then please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply `setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);` at the constructor of your custom `GridView`. Then apply the transformations at the `protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t)`  and `return true` to that overriden function

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339907/3d-cube-transition-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about 3D, i guess probably you should take a look at [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html)

and [openGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

Regarding Renderscript,tutorial are at [Part-I](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html) and [Part-II](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/renderscript.html)

For Best example for the usage of renderscript is Youtube and Books app for Honeycomb 3.0 and above.

Comment: I don't really see the need for renderscript.Too complicated and including it's own logic. Android View is hardware accelerated on Tablets the performance on <480 x800 resolution phones is good without the use of GPU and if that not good enough for some reason there is always OpenGL. But yeah RenderScript is another alternative

Comment: so it means that 3D chile and carousel is possible without openGL and rendersript?

Comment: hey thats great.let us know how could u do it.will be useful to the guys just like me..

Comment: @adhavan I got some hint from this link and i have make some changes in it. http://code.google.com/p/android-flip3d/source/browse/src/?r=9c57a72f60591a422ae72a1b8f86e447cb0f7e57

Comment: yes is possible and very efficient if done correctly.caching views when needed

Answer (score 0):

The flip animation in your link doesn't produce believable 3D flips. A simple rotation on the y-axis isn't sufficient. The zoom effect is also needed to create that nice iOS flip feel. For that, take a look at this example: https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition.

There is also a video here: http://youtu.be/52mXHqX9f3Y