# How to define seperate touch events for horizontally and vertically in android?

Tags: android, touch-event

I have an android application. I have four screens and each screen contains a listview.. My requirement is that when a user flips horizontally then it should change the ui screen and when the user flips vertically it should scroll through the list.My code is

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
     System.out.println("22");
       int eventaction=event.getAction();

         switch(eventaction) 
        {
          case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
              System.out.println("move");
          a=1;
          break;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  System.out.println("up");
              if(a==1)
              {
                  view1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left));
                  view1.showNext();
              }
              a=0;
                  break;

          default:
          break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: @OlofEdler He is not having enough answers on their questions. May be because of he haven't asked question with full detail or may be due to require expertise or else.

Comment: @Paresh. Then what about his comment:  thanks a lot for the code....it is working absolutely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069250 Shound be marked as accepted, no?

Comment: @OlofEdler yes you are right. I just checked question list with no. of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where the children were eating up all the scroll events.  I ended up overiding the `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the parent to detect if it was a horizontal or vertical swipe and acting accordingly.  You would want something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){
    if(horizontalSwipe(ev)){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

where you have some function that determines from your history if the new motion event constitutes a horizontal motion event.