# Android Card flip Animation

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

Im trying to have a card flip animation between activities. I looked at the example given by google but i only got more confused on how it works. I want to be able to click a button and have the card flip animation between two activites. Is there any examples on how to do this using a button and two activities?

Comment: what you did so far add in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge,3D transitions are not supported by window manager.

Behind this there is a reason, that to achieve FLIP animation both views must be loaded to show mirror effect. While activities are stand alone processes in Android.

So If you want such animations better you use fragments rather activities.

But If you still want it with activities. Here is the alternative [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069250/how-to-apply-3d-transition-between-two-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You may again go through the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). They have used fragments. With the use of fragments it is easily achievable. You need a one activity and other fragments to achieve the desire functionality.

Comment: I tried using fragments, however i dont know how to start the card flip animation on a button click. They used on some sort of icon click. I tried replicating what they did but i only got stumpt numerous times.