# 3D cube transition in Android - complete code example

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm searching for a complete code example to make a 3D cube transition from one activity to a second one. please help.
If there is way but only in the same activity (viewFlipper ect) that's ok too.

Something like this -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcOwMgYrjAg

Thank you!

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339907/3d-cube-transition-in-android

Comment: I saw this answer. but it's missing complete code example. it's not clear how to implement.

Comment: @gil hello have got any solution ?

Comment: check out this for demo. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245031/how-to-implement-cube-transition-effect-animation-on-viewpager-in-android/27774196#27774196`

Answer (score 1):

Use below link for complete example of 3D cube transition.

[3D transition animation between Activities](http://www.sfonge.com/forum/topic/3d-transition-animation-between-activities)

[Create a spinning cube with OpenGL ES and Android](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/create-a-spinning-cube-with-opengl-es-and-android/)

Comment: I imported this project. it's not a cube transition.