# how to implement cube Transition effect animation on ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to implement cube Transition effect animation in Android View Pager.

can anyone have an idea about cube animation in android.

[image]

Image is attached for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [3D cube transition in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339907/3d-cube-transition-in-android)

Comment: have you got the solution for your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [here](https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms)

**Snapshot:**

[image]

There you can see the library and related source codes.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.AccordionTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.BackgroundToForegroundTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.CubeInTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.CubeOutTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.DefaultTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.DepthPageTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.FlipHorizontalTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.FlipVerticalTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.RotateDownTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.RotateUpTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.StackTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.TabletTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.ZoomInTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.ZoomOutSlideTransformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.ZoomOutTranformer;
import com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms.example.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnNavigationListener {

    private static final String KEY_SELECTED_PAGE = "KEY_SELECTED_PAGE";
    private static final String KEY_SELECTED_CLASS = "KEY_SELECTED_CLASS";
    private static final ArrayList<TransformerItem> TRANSFORM_CLASSES;

    static {
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES = new ArrayList<TransformerItem>();
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(DefaultTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(AccordionTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(BackgroundToForegroundTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(CubeInTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(CubeOutTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(DepthPageTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(FlipHorizontalTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(FlipVerticalTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(RotateDownTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(RotateUpTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(StackTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(TabletTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(ZoomInTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(ZoomOutSlideTransformer.class));
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(ZoomOutTranformer.class));
    }

    private int mSelectedItem;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int selectedPage = 0;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_CLASS);
            selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_PAGE);
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<TransformerItem> actionBarAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TransformerItem>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, TRANSFORM_CLASSES);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(actionBarAdapter, this);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        //noinspection ResourceType
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() ^ ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(selectedPage);

        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(mSelectedItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
        mSelectedItem = position;
        try {
            mPager.setPageTransformer(true, TRANSFORM_CLASSES.get(position).clazz.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_SELECTED_CLASS, mSelectedItem);
        outState.putInt(KEY_SELECTED_PAGE, mPager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "EXTRA_POSITION";
        private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] { 0xFF33B5E5, 0xFFAA66CC, 0xFF99CC00, 0xFFFFBB33, 0xFFFF4444 };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final int position = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_POSITION);
            final TextView textViewPosition = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            textViewPosition.setText(Integer.toString(position));
            textViewPosition.setBackgroundColor(COLORS[position - 1]);

            return textViewPosition;
        }

    }

    private static final class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(PlaceholderFragment.EXTRA_POSITION, position + 1);

            final PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

    }

    private static final class TransformerItem {

        final String title;
        final Class<? extends PageTransformer> clazz;

        public TransformerItem(Class<? extends PageTransformer> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
            title = clazz.getSimpleName();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: how to use this library can you help me.

Comment: @saikrupa download and import that sample in studio.Then check what are the things you need to add it in your real time project.

Comment: is this a library or some sample project

Comment: How to do this between two activities?

Comment: Just visit their GitHub Repo on this, ToxicBakery.

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: HI there is extra spacing while transformation , can you please help me in modifying this? @DelacrixMorgan

Comment: @RishabhSaxena I've created a gist down below for you to fine tune your Cube Transformation.

Comment: @DelacrixMorgan Thanks :)

Comment: @Luffy I have 4 screens, it would be great if it just kept paging (infinite scroll)  
ie 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 1 and have the animation keep going in the correct direction. Also have it working in both directions ie. 1 backwards to 4.  I can get the scrolling working, just not the animation.

Answer (score 6):

I've written a ViewPager.PageTransformer specifically just for the Cube Transformation Effect.

Feel free to adjust the `deltaY` to fine tune your vertical transformation. Cheers mate.

https://gist.github.com/delacrixmorgan/6b05ab74d1acb01b471fcc3151d70703

Answer (score 1):

This is [Morgan Koh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53331906/2200951) but in Java and using ViewPager2.

`position` is the distance betweeen the seam (between the two panels displayed) and the edge of the screen. (This fires many times as you drag the seam across.)

```
public class CubeTransformer implements ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
        float deltaY = 0.5f;
        float pivotX = position < 0f ? page.getWidth() : 0f;
        float pivotY = page.getHeight() * deltaY;
        float rotationY = 45f * position;

        page.setPivotX(pivotX);
        page.setPivotY(pivotY);
        page.setRotationY(rotationY);
    }
}
```

And then in your activity:

```
ViewPager2 vp = findViewById(R.id.swipe_frame);
vp.setAdapter(new SwipeAdapter());
vp.setPageTransformer(new CubeTransformer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use camera to perform such animation.
Try to read com.example.android.apis.animation.Transition3d in ApiDemos.