# 3D "cube" animation between Activities in Android

Tags: android, animation

I need animation between Android Activities. I have tried some examples but can't find something like this:

[image]

Comment: Video doesn't get loaded at all. Am waiting for ages here. Anything else you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) Project and mark as Library in project property and add it to your project

Create your activity like this:

```
package com.example.testcube;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager;
import com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager.TransitionEffect;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JazzyViewPager vpage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set window fullscreen and remove title bar, and force landscape orientation
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupJazziness(TransitionEffect.CubeOut);
    }

    private void setupJazziness(TransitionEffect effect) {
        vpage = (JazzyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.jazzy_pager);
        vpage.setTransitionEffect(effect);
        vpage.setAdapter(new MainAdapter());
        vpage.setPageMargin(0);
    }

    private class MainAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            TextView text = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setTextSize(30);
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            text.setText("Page " + position);
            text.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
            int bg = Color.rgb((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64, 
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64,
                    (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64);
            text.setBackgroundColor(bg);
            container.addView(text, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            vpage.setObjectForPosition(text, position);
            return text;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
            container.removeView((View) obj);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }       
    }

}
```

and in your activity XML should be

```
<com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/jazzy_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own 3D cube animation using the [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) method. See [3D cube transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339907/3d-cube-transition-in-android).

There are two demos in the API demos called `Transition3d` and `Rotate3dAnimation` that can be useful as references for how to achieve this animation effect. The following blog has an example based on these APi demos for a 3D Activity transition: [Android startActivity rotate 3d animation: ActivitySwitcher](http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/).